# arduino parking lot

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, sensors, rfid, infrared

I want to make a project where there is a parking lot and a ir sensor which senses when a car comes and displays a message on lcd saying to insert a rfid card and then it opens a gate and there are many ir sensors in the slots to detect where there are cars and sends a message saying which slot is free.but the problem is many parts need the 5v pin but there is only one on the arduino board so i wanted to ask if any problem will occur if we connect multiple parts to one 5v pin if there will be a problem what is the work around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect multiple devices or modules to the same 5v pin, as long as it does not exceed the maximum current that the on-board 5v regulator can handled. If you are using a genuine [Arduino Uno](https://content.arduino.cc/assets/UNO-TH_Rev3e_sch.pdf), it has a [NCP1117](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NCP1117-D.PDF) which has a maximum current of 1A. If you don't have a genuine Arduino Uno, check the part number and find the datasheet to find out the maximum current.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Welcome. If this help and answered your question, please consider to [accept the answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).